# Tabbar issues in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, listactivity, tabbar

Currently i am working in Android application, Using Tabbar to create five tabs like 1,2,3,4 and 5. 1st tab using ListActivity to create ListView, when i select the ListItem from ListView, the ListItem value goes to 3rd tab and also i am getting the value in 3rd tab fine, but the problem is the value pass from 1st tab to 3rd tab, at the time 1st tab only selected, but i want 3rd tab select.
How to fix this?, please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Source code for your reference:

1st Tab :

```
     @Override
     protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, final View v, int position, long id) 
     {
      super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

      String SelectedItem = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
      System.out.println("Selected Item: "+ SelectedItem);
      System.out.println("position Item: "+ position);

       String SelectedPhoneNumber  = phoneNumber.get(position);
       System.out.println("SelectedPhoneNumber  " + SelectedPhoneNumber);

     // Using TabGroupActivity, so
       Intent i = new Intent(getParent(), 3rdTab.class);
      i.putExtra("DestinationNumber", SelectedPhoneNumber);
     TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
     parentActivity.startChildActivity("Sample", i);
   }
```

1. TabGroupActivity.java

   public class TabGroupActivity extends ActivityGroup
   {

   ```
   private ArrayList<String> mIdList;

    @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
           if (mIdList == null) mIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
       }


    @Override
     public void finishFromChild(Activity child) 
    {
         LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
         int index = mIdList.size()-1;

         if (index < 1)
         {
             finish();
             return;
         }

         manager.destroyActivity(mIdList.get(index), true);
         mIdList.remove(index); index--;
         String lastId = mIdList.get(index);
         Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();
         Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent);
         setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
     }

    public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {     
         Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
         if (window != null) {
             mIdList.add(Id);
             setContentView(window.getDecorView()); 
         }    
     }


     @Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
             //preventing default implementation previous to android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
             return true;
         }
         return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
     }

     /**
      * Overrides the default implementation for KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK 
      * so that all systems call onBackPressed().
      */
     @Override
     public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
     {
         if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
         {
             onBackPressed();
             return true;
         }
         return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
     }

     @Override
     public void  onBackPressed  () 
     {
         int length = mIdList.size();
         if ( length > 1) 
         {
             Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(mIdList.get(length-1));
             current.finish();
         }       
     }


   }
   ```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. You say "at the time only 3rd tab select, but i want 3rd tab select," which makes it sound as though you are getting exactly the behavior you expect.

Please also be aware that variables (such as your Strings) should start with lowercase letters, as per the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

Comment: My problem is the value pass from 1st tab to 3rd tab, at the time 1st tab only selected, but i want 3rd tab select.

Comment: please help me, waiting for your reply

Comment: Can you link to the TabGroupActivity implementation you are using? TabGroupActivity is not a native Android class.

Comment: Using TabGroupActivity for tabbar sometimes hide, when Intent to next screen from tab2.

Comment: Than how to fix this issue? please helpe me

Comment: I really need to see the TabGroupActivity code. Again, this is not a native Android feature, so I have no idea how your TabGroupActivity works.

Comment: please see above, TabGroupActivity for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked through the sample application at the bottom of [this post](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)?

More specifically:

- Does your main activity follow the format of TabSample.java and add the tabs to a TabHost?
- Do your tabbed Activities extend TabGroupActivity? You can see in the sample that the author creates a new class that extends TabGroupActivity for each tab (eg TabGroup1Activity, TabGroup2Activity), then each of *those* Activities launches another activity (such as OptionsActivity or EditActivity).

If all else fails, you should also be able to manually change the selected tab using `tabHost.setCurrentTab(int tabIndex)`.